# What is a "match flip"?

Tags: meaning

In "Go Set A Watchman", a "match flip" is used in the process of lighting a cigarette:

> "I smoke sometimes, now. It's my one concession to old age. I find myself becoming anxious sometimes ... it gives me something to do with my hands."
>
> Jean Louise found a match flip on the table by her chair. She struck one and held it to her uncle's cigarette.

Comment: I assume it's talking about a "match book".

Answer (score -1):

It would likely mean a stand with an upright matchbox open at the top. The box offers a match and the stand holds the box without blocking access to its sides for striking the match. This with an ashtray at the bottom would be standard furniture for cock-tale bars and saloons.

Comment: I would be interested in your source. I was unable to turn up anything during my online search.

Comment: More commonly known as a match stand or flip. It holds a box of matches for easy access to a smoker. I have seen them in antique shops up until smoking disappeared and grew up in a house that always had a few in the living room.